# What's the equivalent of "facet_filter" field of facets, but for aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider this good request using **facets**:

```
{
   "facets": {
      "tag": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "text"
         },
         "facet_filter": {
            "term": {
               "lang": "en"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I switch to `aggregations` instead of `facets` with the facet_filter feature?

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "tag": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "text"
         },
         "facet_filter": {       <--- Not working
            "term": {            
               "lang": "en"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "tag": {
          "filter" : { "term" : { "lang" : "en" } },
          "aggs" : {
            "tag": {
              "terms" : { "field" : "text" }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the request and response: http://yaap.it/paste/14031049226e045a#jiVNZCVxVK++UJJMeBYcylIg1I7S2UNOExBxymlYpAo=

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Take a look of the request and the response: http://yaap.it/paste/a6a541f95e5d96eb#nK0SdVd7tqzsFOPwT6CwvnEjcnrHkJn8FYXq4yT0akU=

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the naming of the aggregation. I've edited the snippet in the answer.